# Requesting HTTP HEAD of thousands of URLs via NodeJS

Tags: node.js, http

I need to check the availability of about 300.000 URLs on a local server via HTTP. The files are not in a local file system but a key value store and the goal is to sanity check if every system needing access to those files is able to do so vial HTTP.

To do so, I would use HTTP HEAD requests that return HTTP 200 for every file found and 404 for every file not found.

The problem is, if I do too many requests at once, I get rate limited by nginx or a local proxy, hence no info whether a file is really accessible.

My method to look for the availability of files looks as follows:

```
...
const request = require('request'); // Using the request lib.
... 
const checkEntity = entity => {
logger.debug("HTTP HEAD ", entity);
return request({ method: "HEAD", uri: entity.url })
    .then(result => {
        logger.debug("Successfully retrieved file: " + entity.url);
        entity.valid = result != undefined;
    })
    .catch(err => {
        logger.debug("Failed to retrieve file.", err);
        entity.valid = false;
    });
}
```

If I call this function a few times, things work as expected. When trying to run it within recursive promises, I quickly exceed the maximum stack. Setting up one promise for each call causes too much memory usage.

How could this be solved?

Comment: You can make a queue to store all `uri`, and send 10 HTTP requests at once. Then, only when 1 request is handled (get response), fetch a new `uri` from queue and request that. In this way, only 10 requests are under processing at any time.

Comment: How do I make a queue? http and request either require a callback function or, in the case of request-promise, I have a promise for each URL to check.

Comment: Actually, your HTTP request promise has already been handled by `.then` and `.catch`, all you need to do is add a `callback` parameter in the `checkEntity` function to notify the end of one request. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved in these steps:

1. Define a queue and store all your `entities` (all URLs that need to be checked).
2. Define how many HTTP requests you want to send in parallel. This number should not be too small or too large. If it's too small, the program is not efficient. If it is too large, current requests-number-limit problem will occur. Let's make it as `N`, you can define a reasonable number according to your server status.
3. Send `N` HTTP requests in parallel at the beginning.
4. When 1 request is finished, fetch a new `entity` from the queue and send a new request. To get notified when request is done, you can add a *callback* parameter in your `checkEntity` function.

In this way, the maximum HTTP requests number will never be more than `N`.

Here is a pseudo code example based on your code snippet:

```
let allEntities = [...]; // 300000 URLs
let finishedEntities = [];

const request = require('request'); // Using the request lib.
...
const checkEntity = function(entity, callback) {
  logger.debug("HTTP HEAD ", entity);
  return request({ method: "HEAD", uri: entity.url })
    .then(result => {
      logger.debug("Successfully retrieved file: " + entity.url);
      entity.valid = result != undefined;
      callback(entity);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      logger.debug("Failed to retrieve file.", err);
      entity.valid = false;
      callback(entity)
    });
}
function checkEntityCallback(entity) {
  finishedEntities.push(entity);
  let newEntity = allEntities.shift();
  if (newEntity) {
    checkEntity(allEntities.shift(), checkEntityCallback);
  }
}

for (let i=0; i<10; i++) {
  checkEntity(allEntities.shift(), checkEntityCallback);
}
```

To make things easier to understand, you can change the usage of `request` and remove all Promise stuff:

```
const checkEntity = function(entity, callback) {
  logger.debug("HTTP HEAD ", entity);
  request({ method: "HEAD", uri: entity.url }, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
      logger.debug("Failed to retrieve file.", error);
      entity.valid = false;
      callback(entity);
      return;
    }
    logger.debug("Successfully retrieved file: " + entity.url);
    entity.valid = body != undefined;
    callback(entity);
  });
}
```